# Макрос, который зависит от аргументов

Tags: c++, c, препроцессор

Хочется макрос, который расширяется в разное в зависимости от наличия или отсутствия у него аргументов. Пример:

```
_return();     /* расширяется в return(0xDEAFBEEF); */
_return(a+b);  /* расширяется в return(a+b);        */
```

Как?

В принципе набрёл на [такую ветку](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.std.c/d-6Mj5Lko_s/jqonQLK20HcJ), но дальше что? Ну узнали мы сколько аргументов, и...

Comment: Между прочим (хулиганство, конечно), но можете и прямо `return()` и `return(expr)` (без подчеркиваний) так расширить.

Comment: Можно. Но хотелось бы явно глазами отличать где используется честный вариант и где подмены.

Comment: И это правильный подход.

Comment: #define TRUE (time(0)&1) и пусть мучаются  с отладкой :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Немного поправил исходный комплект макросов по ссылке. Вот что получилось:

```
#define __VA_NARG__(...) \
        __VA_NARG_(_0, ## __VA_ARGS__, __RSEQ_N())
#define __VA_NARG_(...) \
        __VA_ARG_N(__VA_ARGS__)
#define __VA_ARG_N( \
         _1, _2, _3, _4, _5, _6, _7, _8, _9,_10, \
        _11,_12,_13,_14,_15,_16,_17,_18,_19,_20, \
        _21,_22,_23,_24,_25,_26,_27,_28,_29,_30, \
        _31,_32,_33,_34,_35,_36,_37,_38,_39,_40, \
        _41,_42,_43,_44,_45,_46,_47,_48,_49,_50, \
        _51,_52,_53,_54,_55,_56,_57,_58,_59,_60, \
        _61,_62,_63,N,...) N
#define __RSEQ_N() \
        62, 61, 60,                             \
        59, 58, 57, 56, 55, 54, 53, 52, 51, 50, \
        49, 48, 47, 46, 45, 44, 43, 42, 41, 40, \
        39, 38, 37, 36, 35, 34, 33, 32, 31, 30, \
        29, 28, 27, 26, 25, 24, 23, 22, 21, 20, \
        19, 18, 17, 16, 15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10, \
         9,  8,  7,  6,  5,  4,  3,  2,  1,  0

#define JOIN(x,y) _JOIN(x,y)
#define _JOIN(x,y) x##y

#define r(...) JOIN(r,__VA_NARG__(__VA_ARGS__))(__VA_ARGS__)
#define r0() nullargs()
#define r1(x) oneargs(x)

r(x);
r();
```

Тестирую на cpp из gcc. Получил в результате всех подстановок:

```
oneargs(x);
nullargs();
```

Двойная передача JOIN->_JOIN->## - иначе не разворачиваются макроаргументы.

Операция препроцессора `##` склеивает без пробелов и получается новый идентификатор. В макросах с переменным числом аргументов `##` после запятой и перед `__VA_ARGS__` убирает запятую, если аргументов нет - это расширение gcc, поэтому в других компиляторах может не работать.

Comment: Спасибо, работает! И принцип понятен :) У меня тоже gcc, интересно, оно где-то ещё работать будет?

Comment: Здорово получилось. Практически function overload в Си. Только опишите, для чего нужно `##` в `__VA_NARG_(_0, ## __VA_ARGS__, __RSEQ_N())` (на всякий случай, вот [тут](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Variadic-Macros.html) написано).

Comment: "Практически function overload в Си" - мне тут недавно лямбду для C показали :)

Comment: @PinkTux,  в gcc есть  вложенные функции, т.е. с практической т.з. то же, что и лямбды.